# greedy regex error in python while searching html tags

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I am new to `python` `regex`

I know how to use `'?'` to solve the greedy problem
and the below example shows how it works:

```
str2=' "anupam""behera" '
match2=re.search(r'".*?"',str2)
print match2.group()'
```

I get output `"anupam"`

But it doesn't work in the following case:

```
str='<a href="/wiki/Main_Page" title="Visit the main page [z]" accesskey="z">Main page</a>'
match=re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)">(.*)</a>',str)
for link in match:
print link[0]
```

I'm expecting to get ouput as `:/wiki/Main_Page`. But instead I get : `"/wiki/Main_Page" title="Visit the main page [z]" accesskey="z">Main page`

Comment: This question is really a part of a larger problem, whose solution is to stop parsing HTML with regex.

Answer (score 4):

To address your question, you need to be more specific, like:

```
r'<a href="(.*?)"\s.*?>(.*)</a>'
```

However, don't use regex to parse html/xml as noted in this [famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62138).

Use a parser like lxml. See how easy and natural this is:

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring
tag = '<a href="/wiki/Main_Page" title="Visit the main page [z]" accesskey="z">Main page</a>'

tag = fromstring(tag)

print tag.attrib.get('href')
```

prints:

```
/wiki/Main_Page
```

Combine this power with something like [xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) or [css selectors](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html) and you will have no issues parsing any html or xml formats.